# Create a HTML span as a text using java / javascript

Tags: java, html, css, gwt

I need to induce a style property (color) to a selected text in a html div. This html div is created dynamically and is not accessible as a DOM element. Is there a way to do this ?

I have tried this : - inducing a html span (having the required style) along with the selected text.

```
      String data="hello";
      String sig= "its me !!"+"<span style=\"color:orange;\"> + data +
                  "</span>";
      widget.setData(sig);
```

I need the data alone in orange color. The widget internally handles the dynamic creation of the required div.

The characters "<" and ">" is converted to "&lt" and "&gt" and is shown as text instead of the span element. Is there a way to fix this. ?

Is there any way to inject HTML as string?

Comment: What does that have to do with Polymer ?

Comment: The resolution depends on what type is your `widget` element; some widgets allow you to set the `HTML` content directly, some do not and perform escaping, as you have discovered.

Comment: Hi JITHIN, it's been over a month since you posted this question and you got 4 answers. If one of those answers was of any help to you, it'd be nice of you to mark it as accepted (the check under the voting arrows). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use GWT to create a span-element and add your style to that element.

Something like this should work:

```
FlowPanel fp = new FlowPanel();

Element el = DOM.createSpan();
el.getStyle().setColor("orange");
el.setInnerHTML("add your data here ...");

fp.getElement().appendChild(el);
```

(I used a FlowPanel because that's a simple div ...)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the second quotes

```
String data="hello";
      String sig= "its me !!"+"<span style=\"color:orange;\">" + data +
                  "</span>";
      widget.setData(sig);
```

on the line where you assign sig

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, special characters <, >, ", /, ; used in the statement above cannot be parsed. You can use the hexadecimal character code as replacement. 
" => \u0022 < => \u003c > => \u003e \ => \u005c

You can take a clue from my code below

```
var str = "hello";
var str2 = "its me !! ";
var startTag = "\u003cspan style=\u0022color:orange;\u0022\u003e";
var endTag = "\u003c/script\u003e;";

console.log(str + " " + str2 + startTag + endTag);
```

Comment: hexadecimal characters are also converted to &lt and &gt and is taken as text

Answer (score 1):

I do exactly that in one of my GWT projects. First, a small custom widget:

```
public class TextSpan extends Widget {
    public TextSpan() {
        setElement(Document.get().createSpanElement());
    }

    public TextSpan(String text) {
        this();
        getElement.setInnerHTML(text);
    }
}
```

And now the code:

```
    String data = "hello";
    TextSpan yourColoredText = new TextSpan(data);
    yourColoredText.getElement().getStyle().setColor("orange"); // you can do this conditionally or take the color parameter from any source without hard-coding it

    Label yourHTML = new Label();
    yourHTML.getElement().setInnerHTML("it's me!!" + yourColoredString.getElement().getString());
```

A `Label` in GWT is just an HTML `div`.

You can add methods to `TextSpan` class to get/set the text (i.e. implement `HasText`, which we actually do, but I left that out because not my code), or to get/set the color.

Comment: Where did you get the SimpleSpan class?

Comment: no need to delete the answer. Just add the code of the SimpleSpan class to clearify it.

Comment: @ElHoss I included the custom class.